# Higher Order Component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am having hard time figuring out the use of High Order component.

I got the theoretical part that they wrap other elements to add functionality and code repetition but I don't understand how they work.

For example here is a simple HOC component I created

```
import React from 'react';

const withClass = (props) = {
  return (
    <div className={props.classes}> {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default withClass;
```

And imported on two places in my container (We can import it in component as well?)

```
import withClass from '../hoc/withclass.js';

<withClass className={classes.App}>
  <button onClick={this.showPersonTrueHandler}>Show Persons </button>
  <Ccockpit
  coatiitle = {this.props.title}
  cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
  cocperson = {this.state.person.length}
  toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler} />
  {person}
  </withClass>
```

Now, Previously I have learned that we use props to pass properties from parent element to child element? so this means we will have `classes.App` passed to HOC component and the content inside `WithClass Tag` as `props.child`

But I don't get it, why exactly do we do it? and what happens when HOC component receives `props.class` and `props.child`?

Comment: The component that you have is not an HOC, but a functional React component.

Comment: `and what happens when HOC component receives props.class and props.child` If you pass a children prop to the component, that prop is overwritten by the content within tags